# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment'

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

In my MVC application, I get an event from the RabbitMQ queue. To start processing the event

```
public void Consume()
{
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory
    {
        //..
    };

    IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
    IModel channel = connection.CreateModel();
    channel.QueueDeclare("MyQueueName", true, false, false, null);

    EventingBasicConsumer consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
    consumer.Received += OnReceived;
    channel.BasicConsume("MyQueueName", true, consumer);
}
```

To process the event I use

```
private async void OnReceived(object model, BasicDeliverEventArgs deliverEventArgs)
{
    var info = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(deliverEventArgs.Body);            
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(info);
    if (model != null)
    {
        await _groupServiceProvider.GetService<IMyService>().ProcessEvent(model);
    }
}
```

Finally, to process/update my model I use

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public MyService(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }        

    public async Task ProcessEvent(MyModel model)
    {
        //.. process model
    }        
}
```

Unfortunatelly when I run my app I get

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.MyService'.
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService service, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>      at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue,TArg](ConcurrentDictionary`2 dictionary, TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg arg)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
>      at MyService.Consumerd__3.MoveNext() in ..\MyService\Consumers.cs:line

Can anyone explain how can I resolve the dependencies, please?

**Edit**

To inject dependency I use *Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection*

```
_groupServiceProvider = new ServiceCollection()                
             .AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfile)) 
             .AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>()                
             .AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment, HostingEnvironment>()
             //..
            .BuildServiceProvider();
```

Comment: You have your DI container set up to provide your service for `IMyService`: E.g., when this is called, it tries to make an instance: `_groupServiceProvider.GetService<IMyService>`.  The problem is you don't have `IHostingEnvironment` wired up for dependency injection, as well.  What version of MVC is this, and what DI container are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use NetCore 1.1.2. To inject dependency I use  _Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection_ (please see **Edit** below)

Comment: And how do you register `IMyService`?  Can you add that code, as well?

Comment: It is the same way as for the _IHostingEnvironment_. I just added `.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>() ` to the _ServiceCollection()_

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?